# Declarar entero de sql en java

Tags: java, sql, netbeans

Quisiera saber como declaro una variable int de sql a java, osea, por ej, en sql precio, y a la hora de invocarlo en java ,quisiera saber como es el tema de las comillas para hacerlas int, probe poner .parseInt y no me deja en la parte de los metodos:

Ejemplo a lo que me refiero:

```
  fila[1] = txtNombre.getText();  (Como serìa para que tome valor int? .setint no me aparece, ni parseint).
```

y para que devuelva:

```
 txtNombre.setText(rs.getString("num"));
```

(Comos seria aca para que tome valor entero de la tabla, para asi hacer calculos con ella).

```
ps.setString(2, txtNombre.getText());
```

(otro ejemplo que quiero transformar a int)

Por otra parte tambien queria preguntar como puedo hacer que un cliente, al elejir una opcion en un combobox se auto completen unos JTextfield,en la misma clase?, siempre conectado a SQL Workbeanch, desde ya muchas gracias!.

Ejemplo:

```
 try {

            String sql = "SELECT * FROM clientes";
            ps = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();

            combcliente.addItem("");

            while (rs.next()) {
                combcliente.addItem(rs.getString("nombre"));
            }
            rs.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            System.err.println("Error consulta :" + ex.getMessage());
        }
```

Este còdigo lo unico que hace es traer a el combobox un dato almacenado en una Jtable de otra clase, quisiera saber como le implemento, para que auto complete con los otros datos restantes de la Jtable a los Jtextfield, que tengo.

Ejemplo: El cliente elije su id , o su nombre. > Juan carlos

> Se auto complete, apellido, direccio, telefono,dni, etc.
>   Espero que se me entienda y si lo plantie mal, no duden en preguntar, estoy atascado acà, muchas gracias!

Comment: Cuando lees desde un conjunto de resultados, si es un entero tienes que usar el método `getInt`, por ejemplo: `rs.getInt("columnaNumerica");` y cuando es para pasarlo a un statement, tienes que hacer la conversión y usar el método `setInt`, por ejemplo: `int datoNum=Integer.parseInt(txtNombre.getText());` y luego: `ps.setInt(1,datoNum);`

Answer (score -1):

Cuando lees los datos que te trae una consulta, los valores numéricos dichos resultados se obtienen con el método [`getInt` de la Interface `ResultSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSet.html#getInt(int)).

Por ejemplo:

Si la consulta es: `SELECT idEmpleado, Nombre FROM empleado`, obtendrías el valor numérico de `idEmpleado` mediante:

```
int idEmpleado=rs.getInt("idEmpleado");
```

Si se trata de una consulta preparada y hay que enviar un valor a una columna numérica de la tabla, entonces debes usar el método [`setInt` de la Interface PreparedStatement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#setInt(int,int))

Si el valor viene de un *getter* o es una cadena, primero hay que convertirlo a entero. Por ejemplo:

Si la consulta es: `SELECT idEmpleado, Nombre FROM empleado WHERE idEmpleado=?`

```
int idEmpleado=Integer.parseInt(txtIdEmpleado.getText());
```

Y lo pasarías al statement, indicado a la izquiera la posición correspondiente:

```
ps.setInt(1,idEmpleado);
```